# Android c++ service at boot time

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, daemon, linux-device-driver

I need to start a service at boot time in android i don't use broadcast receiver  , i wrote a service in c++ because i need access driver libusb layer to communicate with my extrernal device ,the service is working properly if i started manualy,if i want to start the service at boot time means i need to edit inir.rc file in android if i do that it also working good .but the problem is i cant edit the init.rc in all devices. i put my service in Sytem/bin location and edit the init.rc file as follow

```
service sampleservice/system/bin/sampleservice
              oneshot
              disable
```

for manualy i started the service from terminal like this

```
#./system/bin/sampleservice
```

but i cant start the service at each and every time when system restarts do have any idea to start the service at boot time with out edit init.rc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (NDK reference, google groups like *google-ndk*, *android-developers*, etc.), there is no reliable way of starting a native binary as a service other than `init.rc`.

For your particular use case, you might give USB SDK described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/index.html a try. However if this is not sufficient or if you want to support OS API levels below 10, then I believe there is no simple way to achieve what you want.

Providing that your service is not *critical* (i.e. the system does not depend on it), I've seen a couple of threads here and on the groups that advise to create a regular Android application which you would create using ADT. It would be minimal and contain:

- Your C++ service as a packaged native library
- A broadcast receiver that'll receive a notification after system boot (like described here: http://www.androidenea.com/2009/09/starting-android-service-after-boot.html). This receiver would simply start the native service.

This method has also been recommended when installation of the service on non-rooted devices was necessary. However, I have never tried it. I know it's not much, but I wanted to share what I know on the subject.

Comment: thanks for your comment ,and one more thing can i start the native service from broadcast receiver?

Comment: basically - yes. you could use `Runtime.exec()` and run the whole process. *alternatively* you could create a bootstrapping function in the library, which would probably start a separate working thread. then you'd create a JNI method which would call the native bootstrapping function and simply call the JNI method from the receiver.

Comment: i have one doubt , i start my service using broadcast receiver so it starts at boot but i cant access my external devices,if i start my service in terminal like ./system/bin/myservice it's working properly may be this because of permission issue?

Comment: this may be caused by permissions... *how exactly* do you start the service? what exactly are you experiencing? do you observe any exceptions?

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to make sure that the fs is up before you start the service.... A good idea, if you can compile from source, would be to enable Info logs in init code itself.

BR
Subbu